# PHP program flow with multiple queries and arrays?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

Currently I have a page that has at least two different tables created from  different MySQL queries. In terms of layout, should I be creating the page as follows.

```
<?php 
$db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options); 
$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'); 
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Query 1 and table 1 -->
<?php $query = "SELECT * FROM X;"; 


try 
{ 
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->execute(); 
} 

} 
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(); 
?> 

<?php foreach($rows as $row): ?>
// Create table 1 from Query 
<?php endforeach; ?> 




<!-- Query and table 2 -->
<?php $query = "SELECT * FROM Y;"; 

try 
{ 
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->execute(); 
} 

} 
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(); 
?> 
<?php foreach($rows as $row): ?>
// Create table 2 from Query 
<?php endforeach; ?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Or should I be creating `$query1` and `$query2` at the top of my program and creating separate arrays for each instance?

Also is there any good reason to store arrays as _SESSION variables if they were to be recalled a number of times over the course of a session?

Comment: why are you using try but not catch? You may as well not bother using try at all..

Comment: @Option thanks for the tip, I'm a total beginner, learning by adding elements of working code found on the internet together. I'm definitely going to look into the difference between `try` and `catch` now.

Comment: You definitely need to look into PDO somewhat as this is how to **NOT** use PDO.

Comment: As far as code placement is concerned - it really doesn't matter whether it's at the top of the page or somewhere in between. All that it affects is the logic and data flow as the code is interpreted line by line before displaying the contents on the browser. As a programmer one would have to make sure that they pass the controls and data logically between the different segments of the code. `$_SESSION` only becomes relevant when you have multiple pages waiting to access same set of information. Try not to overuse it though. For a single page program, a standalone array is just as fine.

Comment: I closed this question as a duplicate to what does explain a somewhat wider topic. In its light you can tell that all queries have to be run first and only then output is started.

Comment: Would you mind giving me keywords for what you deem that wider topic, I've been looking but feel my keyword choice is a bit off given I'm not getting the answer detail I'd expect.

Comment: @Option Your comment about looking into PDO was very helpful. After I compared usecases, I understood what your mean't. Thanks. EDIT and also on **try/catch** I'd removed catch and it still worked, but now I understand it clearly too!